# Perl command executor with IPC::Run

Tags: perl, asynchronous, ipc

I need to write a "command executor" that does the following:

1. Gathers commands from a database.
2. Spawns $LIMIT amount of commands (that will run asynchronously).
3. When 1 command finishes another one can start (as long as the command $LIMIT isn't reached).
4. The command should not be spawned by a child of the parent (I don't want to run a child process + the command process).
5. Records results to database & log file (exit state, stdout & stderr).
6. Is written in Perl ( or PHP ).

I've tested [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm).  I've only been able to get it to run commands in chunks (X at a a time).  I'd have to wait for those X to complete, then run another chunk.  I could be doing something wrong though - the reference page for it is tough to follow.  Will this do what I need?

I've also found the following which looks promising ([How to write parallel programs in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910689/how-to-write-parallel-programs-in-perl/16911580#16911580)). Will this do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Conditions 2 and 3 are called throttling, and this feature is provided by modules such as [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) and [`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks%3a%3aSuper) (I am the author of Forks::Super).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.

Comment: I forgot that part of the requirement is that we don't fork a child that would run a command (essentially running two processes to perform one task).  It should just be a parent that spawns the command - without a "child" in between.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Because you want to capture STDOUT and STDERR, you're going to have to use an IO::Select loop if you don't want the extra task. That means you'll need to do your own process management, but that's trivial.

Comment: You can `fork`+`exec` (instead of `fork`+`system`) to run a command in a single child process. `Forks::Super` can do this for you, and even emulate the behavior on Windows.

Comment: @mob - exec doesn't return anything though right?  Technically I could redirect the command output to a file in the command itself, but I wouldn't get the exit state of the script.

Comment: You get the exit status in `$?` when you `wait`/`waitpid` on the child. `Forks::Super` also has methods that make this easier.